# Is every group sofic

Tags: group-theory

There exist many sofic groups. Let $G$ be any group, is $G$ sofic? Do there exist groups which are not sofic?

Comment: [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157175/candidates-for-non-sofic-groups) is relevant.

Comment: Presumably the people who voted to close know the answer?

Comment: There are many other possible reasons to vote for closure. (I didn't vote.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known open problem. The consensus of expert opinion is that there are non-sofic groups, but this has not been proved. A popular candidate for a group that might not be sofic is Higman's group
$$\langle w,x,y,z \mid x^w=x^2,y^x=y^2,z^y=z^2,w^z=w^2 \rangle$$
which is infinite but has no nontrivial finite quotients, but nobody has managed to prove that it is not sofic.

Comment: Thanks you for answering my question. I wonder what is the pitfall to verify whether the the Higman's group is sofic or not

Comment: I don't think there is any specific  pitfall to proving this particular example is not sofic. It is more that nobody has any idea in general how to go about proving any group is not sofic - there is nothing to get a hold on. Typically, if we knew that all sofic groups had some other interesting property then we could look for a counterexample for that property, but there are no results of that kind yet. The Higman example is a good candidate because it is hard to imagine how it could be sofic, but of course that is useless for proving anything.

Comment: @DerekHolt, would you give some context as to how you came across Higman's group? Thank you in advance.